# psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: windows, postgresql, installation, postgresql-9.5

I have successfully installed postgresql and added path to my environment variable in windows 10. But the problem is when i try to run `psql postgresql` in command prompt it gives error saying

```
C:\Users\adity>psql postgres
Password for user adity:
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "adity"
```

I am 100% sure my password is correct I have tried reinstalling and uninstalling many time in case i missed password but every time it gives me same error. Although when i try to run from GUI it starts running. This is frustrating and I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The database superuser that was created during database cluster creation is very likely called `postgres`.

So rather than using the default, which is to use the database user whose name is the same as your current operating system user, explicitly specify the database user `postgres`:

```
psql -U postgres
```